# How to make a searching result? Search bar in UICollection View

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I parsed a data from iTunes API with model:

```
struct AlbumData: Codable {
    
    let results: [Result]
    
}

struct Result: Codable {
    
    let artistName, collectionName: String
    let trackCount: Int
    let releaseDate: String
    let artworkUrl100: String
    
}

struct AlbumModel {
    
    let albumsResult: [Result]
    
}
```

and this is NetworkService code:

```
import Foundation

protocol NetworkServiceDelegate {
    func updateInfo (_ manager: NetworkService, album: AlbumModel)
    func errorInfo (error: Error)
}

struct NetworkService {
    
    var delegate: NetworkServiceDelegate?
    
    func fetchAlbums () {
        let urlString = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=eminem&limit=8&entity=album"
        performRequest(with: urlString)
    }
    
    func performRequest(with urlString: String) {
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    delegate?.errorInfo(error: error!)
                    print("Debuggg error \(LocalizedError.self)")
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    if let albums = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
                        delegate?.updateInfo(self, album: albums)
                        print("succses - \(albums)")
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ data: Data) -> AlbumModel? {
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(AlbumData.self, from: data)
            let result = decodedData.results
            let album = AlbumModel(albumsResult: result)
            return album
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    
}
```

after that I appended this data into array:

```
var albums: [AlbumModel] = []
```

now I have array like this:

```
[Itunes_Albums.AlbumModel(albumsResult: [Itunes_Albums_.Result(artistName: "Eminem", collectionName: "The Eminem Show", trackCount: 20, releaseDate: "2002-01-01T08:00:00Z", artworkUrl100: "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music115/v4/61/d5/0a/61d50a3d-4a27-187a-d16f-6b8ce4b62560/source/100x100bb.jpg"), Itunes_Albums_.Result(artistName: "Eminem", collectionName: "Recovery (Deluxe Edition)", trackCount: 19, releaseDate: "2010-06-21T07:00:00Z", artworkUrl100: "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music125/v4/f1/40/ce/f140ce18-f176-7cf9-c220-3958d7747ae6/source/100x100bb.jpg")
```

After that I display this data into collection view

[my SearchViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmYig.png)

after that I want to write some characters to searchBar (name of album) and display that albums, but it doesn't works.

I can show all code:

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var albumCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var albums: [AlbumModel] = []
    var albumsForSearch: [AlbumModel] = []
    var networkService = NetworkService()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = "Search"
        registerCells()
        networkService.delegate = self
        networkService.fetchAlbums()
    }
    
    private func registerCells() {
        albumCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: AlbumCollectionViewCell.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: AlbumCollectionViewCell.identifier)
    }

}

//MARK: - AlbumManagerDelegate

extension SearchViewController: NetworkServiceDelegate {
   
    func updateInfo(_ manager: NetworkService, album: AlbumModel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.albums.append(album)
            self.albumsForSearch = self.albums
            print("CHEEEEEK - \(self.albums)")
            self.albumCollectionView.reloadData()
            
        }
    }
    
    func errorInfo(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

}

//MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource

extension SearchViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return albums.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return albums[section].albumsResult.count       
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AlbumCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath)
            as! AlbumCollectionViewCell
        
            let jData = albums[indexPath.section].albumsResult[indexPath.item]
            cell.albumNameLabel.text = jData.collectionName
            cell.artistNameLabel.text = jData.artistName
            cell.numberOfTracksLabel.text = "\(jData.trackCount) song(s)"
            cell.albumImage.load(urlString: "\(jData.artworkUrl100)")
            cell.dateOfRelease.text = jData.releaseDate.substring(toIndex: 10)
            return cell
    }
}

//MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate

extension SearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        
        let searchView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionReusableView", for: indexPath)
        return searchView
    }
    
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased(), !searchText.isEmpty {
            albumsForSearch = albums.filter { album -> Bool in
                return album.albumsResult.contains { item -> Bool in item.collectionName.lowercased().contains(searchText)
                }
            }
        albumCollectionView.reloadData()
        } else {
            albumsForSearch = albums
        }
   }
}
```

When I write some characters into searchBar nothing changes

Comment: It depends on the data source (array) and the implementation of `numberOfItems` and `cellForItem`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly it is you're struggling with so ill just point out a few things and hope this will solve your issue.

First, I don't know what your `AlbumModel` looks like. Perhaps you can show this code. but it looks like each instance contains more than one albumsResult. Are you expecting exactly one object in albumsResult in this array?

If not, I find this line really strange `item.albumsResult[0]`. That 0 there is a potential for crashes. So my answer doesn't assume there will always be one (And only one) item in that array.

Second, I also find this strange:

```swift
} else {
    searching = false
    albumsForSearch.removeAll()
    albumsForSearch = albums
}
```

You're resetting your array every time you don't find a result. Not sure I can think of a valid reason why you would ever want to do that.

So perhaps this code is what you need:

```swift
if let searchText = let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased(), !searchText.isEmpty {
    // Search text means filter results
    albumsForSearch = albums.filter { album -> Bool in 
        return album.albumResult.contains { item -> Bool in 
            item.collectionName.lowercased().contains(searchText)  
        }
    }
} else {
    // No search text means display everything
    albumsForSearch = albums
}
```

Then you just base your tableview sections and rows on albumsForSearch

Comment: return album.albumResult.contains { item -> Bool in item.collectionName.lowercased().contains(searchText)
Error: Value of type 'AlbumModel' has no member 'albumResult'

That is AlbumModel:

struct AlbumModel {
    let albumsResult: [Result]
}

Comment: I edited my question with full SearchViewController code, if you can, please watch this

Comment: I made a typo...its supposed to be `albumsResult` not `albumResult`. Keep in mind I am writing code without a compiler and without all your code. I'm not about to duplicate your project and test everything out. If I make a small typo you should adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Oh sorry, I changed this typo. Now I have no error, but when I put some characters into searchBar nothing changes :(

Comment: Oh, forgot to call `albumCollectionView.reloadData()`

Comment: Also your searching boolean is flawed. you are setting to true when the search text changes. But what about when you delete the search text? `searching = !searchText.isEmpty` would make more sense. That being said, my code example works if you use the same array when searching and not searching. So all those `if searching` is not necessary. Just always present what `albumsForSearch` has. You just have to make sure to set `albumsForSearch = albums` when you first load your data.

Comment: I remove "if searching", but its still not working(

Comment: I edited my question (I mean code), can you check now?

Comment: And I wanna thank you for your help

Comment: I feel like you took a wrong turn when you created your models and did your API call and I'm helping you to go deeper in the wrong direction. First of all your api call accepts a search term. So unless you're making a screen that lets you filter Eminem albums you should be making new api calls when your search term changes and let the service filter things for you. Second of all, your NetworkService should probably just return [Result] which is an array of your albums and you probably don't need AlbumModel at all.